# np array put 1row to second and vice versa

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an np array with 3 rows.

Is there any easy way to put the first row to the second and the second to first?

I am a beginner to python so I am struggling a little bit

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```py
arr[[0, 1]] = arr[[1, 0]]
```

Instead of the first `0` and the second row `1`, you can switch any rows with that.

Comment: yeah ok thanks a lot!